# html upload: localize browse button

Tags: html, localization, upload, internationalization

How can I make the "browse" button display in another language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't - it's controlled by the browser.

The long answer is you could override it using some [CSS hacks](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html).

Comment: This does not seem to be showing in any other language, I tried it in Firefox and IE11 with my user locale set to French.. http://jsfiddle.net/BMF5t/

Answer (score 7):

Browse button is a part of upload widget, and generally conforms to user's browser language settings. You could replace it altogether with some js/ajax-y thingy, but I don't see the point.

Comment: i.e. to change the button, change your system language settings.

Comment: uhm, I think flybywire looks at it from the website point of view.