# Input type="file" Localization

Tags: input, localization, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Labeling file upload button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button)

Is there a way to localize the text produce by the  tag?

I am using Chrome Browser and it uses the text "Choose File" and "No file chosen" text.

Is there any way to customize this? or at least change this to another language?

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460731/html-upload-localize-browse-button or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button